# Is there a way to show visual diff from a Mercurial Web Server?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, hgserve

A Mercurial Server can be started up just by

```
hg serve
```

and going to

```
localhost:8000
```

but the diff is a text type of diff.  I wonder if there is any way to get a visual diff right from the server (probably by clicking on a file or a changeset), the type of visual diff that is like on kdiff3 or Tortoise SVN diff.  If it can be done, that should be quite cool.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible.

"hg serve" is a bare bone server and does not yet provide the diff rendering capabilities like you see in any client tools like TortoiseHG and client diff tools.

How ever, if you are looking for a server side solution, you could look at **TracMercurial**. While this is a heavy weight solution, it can achieve what you want.

- http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMercurial#CoolFeatures

Also check out the changeset navigation which is what you want.

- http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMercurial#ChangesetNavigation